# What's wrong in this Java Merge Sort program, it won't sort the given array

Tags: java, mergesort

My merge sort program is not sorting the array, but giving me the output as 0,0,0,3,5. The input array is 2,7,9,5,3. Can someone tell me what's wrong in this program?

In the merge function, I have created temporary array brr[],and recursion is used in mergesort function.

```java
public class merge_sort {
    public static void merge(int arr[],int low,int mid,int high){
        int i=low,k=low;
    
        int j=mid+1;
        int brr[]=new int[5];
        while(i<=mid&&j<=high){
            if(arr[i]<arr[j]){
                brr[k]=arr[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
            else{
                brr[k]=arr[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        while(i<=mid){
            brr[k]=arr[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        while(j<=high){
            brr[k]=arr[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        for (int z = 0; z <=high; z++)
        {
            arr[z]=brr[z];
        }
    }

    public static void mergesort(int arr[], int low, int high) {
        if(low<high){
            int mid=(low+high)/2;
            mergesort(arr,low,mid);
            mergesort(arr,mid+1,high);
            merge(arr,low,mid,high);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int arr[]={2,7,9,5,3};
        int arr_size=5;
        mergesort(arr,0,4);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you declare `brr[]=new int[5];`?

Comment: I declared brr[ ] to merge elements from arr into an arbitrary array and then later I copied the sorted elements back into original array arr [ ] from brr [ ] using for loop.

Answer (score -1):

Change required in merge method: You have done mistakes in assignment of indexes among low mid and high of subarrays for the final result array

```
public static void merge(int arr[],int low,int mid,int high){
       
        int n1 = mid - low + 1;
        int n2 = high - mid;
 
        /* Create temp arrays */

        int L[] = new int[n1];
        int R[] = new int[n2];
     
        for (int i = 0; i < n1; ++i)
            L[i] = arr[low + i];
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; ++j)
            R[j] = arr[mid + 1 + j];
 
        /* Merge the temp arrays */
 
        // Initial indexes of first, second and merged subarrays

        int i = 0, j = 0;
 
        int k = low;
        while (i < n1 && j < n2) {
            if (L[i] <= R[j]) {
                arr[k] = L[i];
                i++;
            }
            else {
                arr[k] = R[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }
 
        /* Copy remaining elements if any */

        while (i < n1) {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
 
        while (j < n2) {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Then why is the same function working in C++?